# Firebase: Can't create FImmutableSortedDictionary with keys with same ordering

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting the below error in firebase version 3.2.0:

> Can't create FImmutableSortedDictionary with keys with same ordering!

I'm building a list of words with the below code:

Init

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tests[0].firebase_create()
    tests[1].firebase_create()
    tests[2].firebase_create()
}
```

Create

```
func firebase_create() {

    let ref1 = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    print("ref1: \(ref1)")
    //ref: https://irishthesaurus.firebaseio.com

    ref1.child("test1").setValue(test1)
    ref1.child("test2").setValue(test2)
    ref1.child("test3").setValue(test3)
}
```

Load

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    ref1.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        var i = 0
        for x in snap.children {

            print("X: \(x)")
            i = i + 1
        }
        print("Sum: \(i)")
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: I tested this code with 2.5.1 and it worked. I had to make a slight change to the create function with: let a = ref1.childByAppendingPath("test1") then a.setValue("test1"). However the Load code worked perfectly. On what line are you getting that dictionary error? Also, I assume the parameter test1 in testValue(test1) is supposed to be "test1"? Also, how is your Firebase initially defined - the ref1?

Comment: Right - that was stated in the question. Do you have more info based on my above questions?

Comment: can you post all the code of the context, because you have `ref` and `ref1`

Comment: There' still not enough information in the question to provide an answer.