# Swift Firebase: can't create keys with same order exception

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on a macOS Swift project using Firebase 2.5.1. It's basically a CRUD system.

I changed the way I created my data path from childWithAutoID to a custom string mainly because I wanted to avoid duplicate entries.

I uploaded all my data to Firebase with success with this new path (about 5000 entries). I can retrieve it with the following code:

```
//Constants.booksFirebase equals my parent path of Firebase
Constants.booksFirebase.queryOrderedByChild("rentedCount").queryLimitedToLast(10).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snap in

        let results = snap.value as? NSDictionary

        if let results = results {
            self.books = []

            for obj in results {
                let id = obj.key as! String
                self.books.append(id)
             }
        }
    })
```

**However, if I query for all values, I get an exepection: "Can't create FImmutableSortedDictionary with keys with same ordering!".** The way I query it is exactly the same as the example above without the limit:  `Constants.booksFirebase.queryOrderedByChild("rentedCount").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock:{...}`

The strange thing is that I have another set of data from other path, `Constants.peopleFirebase`, that works with the same logic above but doesn't raise an exception.

I thought that Firebase may be uploading two objects with the same key, but is just a hypothesis.

Do you have any idea what this error means?

I've seen this but it didn't help me:
[Firebase: Can't create FImmutableSortedDictionary with keys with same ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471233/firebase-cant-create-fimmutablesorteddictionary-with-keys-with-same-ordering)

Thanks,
Marcelo

---

Complete error below:

```
2016-08-29 21:42:00.846 ProSaber[16218:19613620] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-08-29 21:42:00.846 ProSaber[16218:19613620] Can't create FImmutableSortedDictionary with keys with same ordering!
2016-08-29 21:42:00.846 ProSaber[16218:19613620] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d934f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93ec4f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94dfa4bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Firebase                            0x00000001001e518f __55+[FTreeSortedDictionary fromDictionary:withComparator:]_block_invoke99 + 143
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d0dc36 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 134
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d0dac9 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 217
6   Firebase                            0x00000001001e4fbc +[FTreeSortedDictionary fromDictionary:withComparator:] + 315
7   Firebase                            0x00000001001dd774 +[FImmutableSortedDictionary fromDictionary:withComparator:] + 105
8   Firebase                            0x00000001001f67b1 +[FSnapshotUtilities internalNodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:atDepth:path:] + 1665
9   Firebase                            0x00000001001f60ea +[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:atDepth:path:] + 120
10  Firebase                            0x00000001001f602e +[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:] + 147
11  Firebase                            0x00000001001f5f29 +[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:] + 55
12  Firebase                            0x00000001002186d1 -[FRepo onDataUpdate:forPath:message:isMerge:tagId:] + 672
13  Firebase                            0x000000010022212a -[FPersistentConnection onDataPushWithAction:andBody:] + 591
14  Firebase                            0x000000010021eed3 -[FPersistentConnection onDataMessage:withMessage:] + 709
15  Firebase                            0x000000010023bd75 -[FConnection onDataMessage:] + 116
16  Firebase                            0x000000010023bcac -[FConnection onMessage:withMessage:] + 282
17  Firebase                            0x000000010023add0 -[FWebSocketConnection appendFrame:] + 360
18  Firebase                            0x000000010023ae8b -[FWebSocketConnection handleIncomingFrame:] + 132
19  Firebase                            0x000000010023679f __31-[FSRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke + 129
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100993070 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100985cc5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010098b112 _dispatch_queue_drain + 351
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100992e24 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 557
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100989dab _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1226
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001009898a5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001009e8336 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001009e5f91 start_wqthread + 13
)
2016-08-29 21:42:00.847 ProSaber[16218:19613620] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't create FImmutableSortedDictionary with keys with same ordering!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d934f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff93ec4f7e objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94dfa4bd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   Firebase                            0x00000001001e518f __55+[FTreeSortedDictionary fromDictionary:withComparator:]_block_invoke99 + 143
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d0dc36 __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 134
5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff94d0dac9 -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 217
6   Firebase                            0x00000001001e4fbc +[FTreeSortedDictionary fromDictionary:withComparator:] + 315
7   Firebase                            0x00000001001dd774 +[FImmutableSortedDictionary fromDictionary:withComparator:] + 105
8   Firebase                            0x00000001001f67b1 +[FSnapshotUtilities internalNodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:atDepth:path:] + 1665
9   Firebase                            0x00000001001f60ea +[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:atDepth:path:] + 120
10  Firebase                            0x00000001001f602e +[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:withValidationFrom:] + 147
11  Firebase                            0x00000001001f5f29 +[FSnapshotUtilities nodeFrom:priority:] + 55
12  Firebase                            0x00000001002186d1 -[FRepo onDataUpdate:forPath:message:isMerge:tagId:] + 672
13  Firebase                            0x000000010022212a -[FPersistentConnection onDataPushWithAction:andBody:] + 591
14  Firebase                            0x000000010021eed3 -[FPersistentConnection onDataMessage:withMessage:] + 709
15  Firebase                            0x000000010023bd75 -[FConnection onDataMessage:] + 116
16  Firebase                            0x000000010023bcac -[FConnection onMessage:withMessage:] + 282
17  Firebase                            0x000000010023add0 -[FWebSocketConnection appendFrame:] + 360
18  Firebase                            0x000000010023ae8b -[FWebSocketConnection handleIncomingFrame:] + 132
19  Firebase                            0x000000010023679f __31-[FSRWebSocket _handleMessage:]_block_invoke + 129
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100993070 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100985cc5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010098b112 _dispatch_queue_drain + 351
23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100992e24 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 557
24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100989dab _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1226
25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001009898a5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001009e8336 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001009e5f91 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using childByAutoId() to avoid possible duplicate keys in my Firebase data. See the discussion on matthew answer for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the error. That sounds odd, but queryOrderedByChild is intended to be used with queryStartingAtValue, queryEndingAtValue or queryEqualToValue. You can still limit the query further afterwards, but I believe the query is expecting parameters and since you are supplying none it doesn't know where to query up to 10 records. For example, if you have 100 records and you query limited to 10 only, there is no way for the query to know which 10 records you are really trying to see out of 100 without those parameters.

Comment: Hi Matthew, I don't think it's related to that. If I query for all items, using ```Constants.booksFirebase.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {...}``` it happens the same error.

Comment: If its not a query issue then I think you are right about it being a duplicate key. Or an issue withe the upload hierarchy. Have you tried removing the large set of data and upload a small set to see if the same occurs?

Comment: I've tried uploading a smaller dataset. Previously, I had 5000 data points. When I uploaded just a 1000, it worked. But 2000 was sufficient to make the crash appear again. I'm removing all forbidden characters + making sure I'm not uploading a nil value, even though that shoudn't make any difference. Even If I tried uploading a key with the same value as a previous one, it should overwrite the previous one shouldn't it? My guess is that maybe two keys with same value were uploaded before one of them was fully 'accepted' by Firebase. I'll do some tests then I tell you more.

Comment: If it works with some data and not all then you know your code is fine. Just an issue with the data format. But you are right. If there are duplicates it should just overwrite them.

Comment: Just verified you cannot import duplicate keys. I added 5 duplicate keys and tested an import. The last of each duplicate in the file overwritten the previous for all cases.

Comment: Yeah, it does overwrite the previous key. But as I said, I think it didn't overwrite the existing values because it did not exist yet (it was uploading). Anyway, one solution for my problem was to use childByAutoID, avoiding possible duplicate keys. One other solution, if my hypothesis is write, would be to check for duplicate values in my data and treat that accordingly, forbidding the duplicated one to be uploaded at the 'same' time. I could be wrong, but maybe because they're next to each other in the data array, it happens to conflict because of the time the async request is processed.